# Reason for graphics turning sharp / pixelated

Tags: .net, vb.net, graphics

I'm letting a combobox draw font names like this:

```
Private Sub cboFontName_DrawItem(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs) Handles cboFontName.DrawItem

    e.DrawBackground()
    If (e.State And DrawItemState.Focus) <> 0 Then
        e.DrawFocusRectangle()
    End If
    Dim objBrush As Brush = Nothing
    Try
        If e.Index > -1 Then
            objBrush = New SolidBrush(e.ForeColor)
            Dim sFontName As String = Me.cboFontName.Items(e.Index).ToString
            Dim nFont As Font = Nothing
            Dim nFontFamily = New FontFamily(sFontName)
            If nFontFamily.IsStyleAvailable(FontStyle.Regular) Then
                nFont = New Font(nFontFamily, 14, FontStyle.Regular)
            ElseIf nFontFamily.IsStyleAvailable(FontStyle.Bold) Then
                nFont = New Font(nFontFamily, 14, FontStyle.Bold)
            ElseIf nFontFamily.IsStyleAvailable(FontStyle.Italic) Then
                nFont = New Font(nFontFamily, 14, FontStyle.Italic)
            End If
            e.Graphics.DrawString(sFontName, nFont, objBrush, e.Bounds)
        End If
    Finally
        If objBrush IsNot Nothing Then
            objBrush.Dispose()
        End If
        objBrush = Nothing
    End Try

End Sub
```

It worked fine all the time, but now (I don't know what I changed), the fonts render sharp / pixelated:

Left is what it looked like some changes ago (nice and smooth), and right is the current pixelated version.

[image]

Also, some third party controls suddenly render pixelated, so it seems to be an application-wide effect. I have no control over how these third party controls render text.

I really have no idea what might have caused this.

What would be a reason for that?

When I call

```
    e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias
```

... it's smooth again, but I do swear that I didn't have to do it before. I only discovered it right now.

ps: The screenshot on the right is from a sandboxed Windows where I ran the working, old version, so don't be surprised at the different scrollbar appearance. It used to work fine on the non-sandboxed Windows, too.

Here's how it looks when I disable ClearType in the Windows Settings:
[image]

Comment: Is the monitor being driven at its native resolution? Is text scaling set to something other than 100%? Is the poor text rendering present in other programs?

Comment: @tmighty The image on the left does not seem anti-aliased, looks like it uses ClearType rendering (when enabled it's the default). Try setting TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit explicitly instead of AntiAlias to see what comes out.

Comment: @Jimi When I set it to ClearTypeGridFit, the font also becomes smooth again.

Comment: @tmighty  And with TextRenderingHint.SystemDefault?

Comment: @Jimi With SystemDefault, it's pixelated.

Comment: ClearType is activated in Windows.

Comment: @tmighty  Well, Text Sharp has an option to render text in different ways in the environment (under Tools/Options/Text Sharp). One of these is non anti-aliased text. But you would see it everywhere in VS. However, since `TextRenderingHint.SystemDefault` gives you pixelated fonts, ClearType is not the default rendering, somehow. If it's related to your program only, it should be a setting in the base class constructor.

Comment: @Jimi I deleted my comment because I noticed that iTextSharp was installed when it still worked fine. Thanks, I'll have a look at the constructor now. Would that be for example myForm.Designer.vb?

Comment: @tmighty Yes, but since a Form is (usually) a partial class, it could be in a couple of files. -- I can reproduce (for what I can see) your current situation only disabling ClearType in the Control Panel, since setting `Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault` or the like will disable a OwnerDraw control events.

Comment: @Jimi Where would I find this line? I tried to locate it using Ctrl+T and the usual search, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: @tmighty What line are you referring to?

Comment: When I disable ClearType in the Windows settings, the fonts in the browser (for example on this website) look totally pixelated. I'm adding a screenshot to my posting.

Comment: I was referring to the line "Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault". I thought I could perhaps find it something in the project settings (for example in App.Config).

Comment: @tmighty  [`Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.setcompatibletextrenderingdefault(v=vs.110).aspx) (see the Remarks section) is set at "Program" level. See also [WindowsFormsApplicationBase.UseCompatibleTextRendering](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase.usecompatibletextrendering(v=vs.110).aspx). Something has modified the default behavior of TextRenderer in your project.

Comment: @Jimi Thanks. I've noticed that my ApplicationEvents.vb is entirely empty, while in a new, clean project, it has the lines "Namespace My... Partial Friend Class...". I added the missing lines, but that didn't change anything yet.

Comment: I've also recreated the form from scratch, and the pixelated effect is there, so it doesn't seem to be something in the form that causes this effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the culprit:

For some reason, this line causes this behaviour:

```
g.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias
```

But I have no idea why doing this causes the pixelation error, and also in all other forms although I don't use this code in the other forms.

Specifically I use it in the following code.
When I comment out the line "g.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias", everything works fine.

```
Public Sub DrawTextWEx(ByRef uBitmap As Bitmap, ByVal uText As String, ByVal uColor As Color, ByVal uStringFormat As StringFormat, ByRef uFont As Font, ByRef uAvailableRect As Rectangle)

    Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(uBitmap)
        g.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias
        Using nBrush As New System.Drawing.SolidBrush(uColor)
            g.DrawString(uText, uFont, nBrush, uAvailableRect, uStringFormat)
        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```